# Adding multiple icons with separate tooltips in JTable

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable, tooltip

I need to show multiple icons in a single column in JTable. I am using an modified Icon implementation.

```
Class IconCollection implements Icon {
    Icon[] icons
}
```

Since it implements Icon interface , I am able to show multiple icons in single column. However I need to assign separate tooltips for each icon. Since `JComponent` has single `setToolTipText()` method, it is not possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `JTable` has a decent implementation of `getTooltipText` which delegates to the component of the renderer, you can completely solve this in the renderer.

In the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method you can return any `JComponent`. If you would opt for a `JPanel` containing multiple icon instances with each a correct tooltip (instead of your big icon).

Comment: +1 I'd be to use JLabel retuned from Renderer, with proper LayoutManager, GridLayout??? e.i.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component to contain your icons and override `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)`, basing the text returned on the relative position of the mouse.